# Scale method in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm using the `zoom()` function when a user clicks on the `zoom_in`, `zoom_out` buttons. The `img_update()` function is used to redraw the canvas element.

Now zoom works only after I'm painting on the canvas, but I'd like to see zoom effect immediately after the user clicks on the zoom buttons. How can I fix this?

```
function zoom() {
    switch(this.id) {
        case "zoom_in":
            scale /= scaleMultiplier;
            img_update(scale);
            break;
        case "zoom_out":
            scale *= scaleMultiplier;
            img_update(scale);
            break;
    }
}

function img_update( scale ) {
    redoArray.length = 0;
    flag = 0;
    contextUI.scale(scale, scale);
    contextUI.transform(scale, scale);
    contextUI.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

}
```

Comment: I think we need a bit more code here.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is scale is undefined when you first try to click zoom, though after it's been rendered, then it is defined.  console log everything